# Embedding Vimeo Album Without Flash

Tags: jquery, html, flash, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to quickly embed a Vimeo album using their Hubnut widget, but it doesn't work without Flash. I want to use an iFrame with the album's direct link as an alternative, but it's no bueno. When I check console, it says, "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://vimeo.com/album/xxxxxx does not permit cross-origin framing." Is there any way around this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var flash = swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion('1') ? true : false;
    if (flash) {
        $('#embed').html('<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/hubnut/album/xxxxxx?color=a13647&amp;background=0f0f0f&amp;slideshow=0&amp;video_title=1&amp;video_byline=0" style="display: block;" width="758" height="426" border="0" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen seamless></iframe>');
    } else {
        $('#embed').html('<iframe src="https://vimeo.com/album/xxxxxx" style="display: block;" width="758" height="426" border="0" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe>');
    }
});
</script>
<div id="embed">
    <p><a href="https://vimeo.com/album/xxxxxx" target="_blank">View Virtual Tours</a></p>
</div>
```